# Will User.Identity.Name generates the same data as Membership.GetUser().UserName

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

As per my question. Will this generates the same username for anonymous and logged in user?

EDIT: sorry for the confusing question. What I'm trying to find out is that if User.Identity.Name is a reliable way to get the username of currently logged in user. Trying to avoid Membership.GetUser().Username as GetUser() might return null for anonymous user.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not sure *Generate* is the best word.  I'm going to assume you meant *Return the same data*.

The answer is *not always*.

`User.Identity` is an `IIdentity` instance (typically a [GenericIdentity](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.principal.genericidentity.aspx) or a [WindowsIdentity](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.principal.windowsidentity.aspx)).

`Membership.Getuser()` will return a instance of [MembershipUser](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.membershipuser.aspx).

Both of these mechanisms can be customized and technically can return completely different information.

**Updated for Edit**

First, this question is starting to sound like an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378).  I highly suggest you let us know what you are *actually trying to solve*.

Although `Membership.GetUser()` should return null for anonymous users, `User.Identity.Name` normally returns `string.Empty` for anonymous users which also isn't technically correct.

Typically the recommended way is to do something like:
(taken directly from the in the ASP.Net MVC 3 Template starter)

```
@if(Request.IsAuthenticated) 
{
  <text>Welcome <b>@Context.User.Identity.Name</b>!
  [ @Html.ActionLink("Log Off", "LogOff", "Account") ]</text>
}
else 
{
  @:[ @Html.ActionLink("Log On", "LogOn", "Account") ]
}
```